# copy table to mysql to mysql

Tags: ssis

> Hi all
>
> I want to copy table from mysql to mysql.
>
> Source MYSQL server IP is :172.16.10.50
>
> Destination MYSQL server IP is :172.16.10.152
>
> I used ADO.Net source and Ado.Net Destination.
>
> but at time of execution i faced this error.
>
> [ADO NET Destination [16]] Error: An exception has occurred during
>   data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"status",
>   "status_name", "selectable", "campaign_id", "human_answered",
>   "categor' at line 1
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
>   ProcessInput method on component "ADO NET Destination" (16) failed
>   with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination
>   Input" (19). The identified component returned an error from the
>   ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the
>   error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.
>
> Kindly help me to resolve this issue.
>
> Regards
>   Neha Prajapati

Answer (score 0):

If you read your error message carefully (or maybe vaguely enough) you can see that the error message states that you have  a **Syntax Error**. What is the query that you are trying to run through SSIS?

Comment: I'm using Query in source and map directly table to destination. mapping is fine. but execution gives error. my source query is :SELECT     status, status_name, selectable, campaign_id, human_answered, category, sale, dnc, customer_contact, not_interested, unworkable, scheduled_callback
FROM       vicidial_campaign_statuses v   

and destination is Astersik.vicidial_campaign_statuses

and execution source in green and destination in red .. source reflect that it fetch 3 rows.

Comment: Check the data types and the size of each column in the destination. Its possible that the data on some column might be getting truncated.

Comment: Thanx rajiv for reply. actually i have already a table at destination which i can't alter same with source .. is there any another logic so i can execute this.